# Permissibility of using present perfect with adverbs such as "earlier" and "previously"

Tags: present-perfect

Can the "present perfect" tense be used with adverbs such as "earlier," "previously", etc. that refer to an unspecific time in the past? Here are two examples:

1. I have talked to you about this point earlier, but let me
   quickly go over it one more time.
2. Those who have previously contracted covid19 should stay in this
   room.

Note. The reason why I used the "present perfect" tense in the above sentences is that I wanted to talk about an incident that occurred in the past but its exact time is not important. I've heard that "present perfect" should be used in those cases. For example, see application 2 in this [reference](https://www.shoreline.edu/bbell/images/UsesforPresentPerfect.htm#:%7E:text=The%20present%20perfect%20is%20often,in%20Canada%20for%20five%20years.).

Answer (score 1):

> I have talked to you about this point earlier, but let me quickly go over it one more time

The main purpose of [present perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect) is to indicate that something has an effect that lasts until the present.

> I have booked a room - *the booking exists now*
> I have read this book - *the information is in my head*

If you provide even the slightest indication of when something happened, you use past simple rather than present perfect, to indicate that the time it happened is more important than the lasting effect.

> I booked the room on Thursday - *correct*
> I have booked the room on Thursday - *incorrect*

Looking at your first sentence, it is grammatically correct but the meaning may not be what you intended. The presence of **earlier** is enough to indicate that the time it happened (before now) is more important than the effect lasting to present, so **have** is understood to be an [emphatic auxiliary](https://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/emphatic-form.html#:%7E:text=Emphatic%20forms%2C%20sometimes%20called%20the,he%20does%20work%20very%20hard.%22). In spoken English, the word **have** would be stressed.

> I **have** talked to you about this point earlier, but let me quickly go over it one more time.

If you don't want to make it emphatic, you should omit the **have**:

> I talked to you about this point earlier, but let me quickly go over it one more time.

Comment: Thank you for all this good information. I really appreciate it! I think it helps if I provide a bit more context. In the above conversation, there is a strong "effect lasting to present" aspect. The speaker believes memories of what they are about to share **presently** exist in the mind of the audience. The main goal of the first sentence is to give a heads-up about these memories to avoid possible confusion. Can you please share what you would say in such situations?